# Infinite loop when fetching userData in real-time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I was trying to render a list of users coming from my database. When trying to update any data, it should reflect real-time in the frontend. However, it creates this loop when calling the list of users. Here is my code:

```
async function fetchUserData() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:3000/user-data?limit=4"
    );
    setuserData(res.data);
  }
  fetchuserData();

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connected to server");
    });
    socket.on("message", (data) => {
      console.log("Received message:", data);
      setuserData((prevData) => [...prevData, data]);
    });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

In case you will be looking at my userData.map, here's the code

```
{userData.map((type, index) => (
<h2
className={`bg-${
index % 2 === 0 ? "blue-100" : "white"
} p-5 font-medium text-4xl text-center flex-1`}
key={type.id}
>
{type.name}
</h2>
))}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that userData should be called when database changes is present in real-time and also to prevent this infinite loop I am encountering. Thank you

Comment: You have to call `fetchuserData` inside the `useEffect`, otherwise it will be called on every render.

Comment: I have placed `fetchuserData` inside the `useEffect`, however when updating values in the database, the updated value does not appear in real-time